# Ignore null entries in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

The example below builds a table that extracts the first two score values by userId and passageId. How can I select only records where each record in the new table contains at least two scores (i.e. ignore records where score2 is null)?

[Example](http://rextester.com/PHJK76523)

Code:

```
 drop table if exists simon;
 drop table if exists simon2;
 Create table simon (userId int, passageId int, score int);
 Create table simon2 (userId int, passageId int, score1 int,score2 int);    

 INSERT INTO simon (userId , passageId , score )
 VALUES
 (10, 1, 2),
 (10, 1, 3),
 (10, 2, 1),
 (10, 2, 1),
 (10, 2, 5),
 (11, 1, 1),
 (11, 2, 2),
 (11, 2, 3),
 (11, 3, 4);

 insert into simon2(userId,passageId,score1,score2)
 select t.userId, t.passageId,
 substring_index(t.scores,',',1) as score1,
 (case when length(t.scores) > 1 then substring_index(t.scores,',',-1) 
  else null
  end
 ) as score2
 from 
 (select userId,passageId,
 substring_index (group_concat(score separator ','),',',2) as scores
 from simon
 group by userId,passageId) t;

 select *from simon2;
```

This is what I get now:

```
   userId   passageId   score1  score2
1   10      1           2       3
2   10      2           1       1
3   11      1           1       NULL
4   11      2           2       3
5   11      3           4       NULL
```

This is what I want:

```
   userId   passageId   score1  score2
1   10      1           2       3
2   10      2           1       1
4   11      2           2       3
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this around your query

```
Select * from ( ...... ) x where score2 is not null
```

Comment: #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'insert into simon2(userId,passageId,score1,score2)

Answer (score 0):

You have no ordering specifying what score goes into `score_1` and `score_2`, so I'll just use `min()` and `max()`.  You can then do the logic as:

```
select s.userid, s.passageid,
       max(score) as score_1, max(score) as score_2
from simon s
group by s.userid, s.passageid
having count(*) >= 2;
```

This doesn't give you exactly the same results for 10/2.  However, your results are arbitrary because the `group_concat()` has no order by.  SQL tables represent *unordered* sets.  There is no ordering unless you specify it.

If you want an ordering, then define the table as:

```
Create table simon (
    simonId int auto_increment primary key,
    userId int,
    passageId int,
    score int
);
```

And then use the `simonId` column appropriately.

Comment: If I add ordering, as you suggest, how to I ignore the null entries?

Comment: Please clarify your comment. First, what do you mean by: 'This doesn't give you exactly the same results for 10/2.' Second, would you please check the solution code you provided. I added the auto_increment you suggested, and tried your code but cannot get it to work.

Comment: @SimonRH . . . My code is fine:  http://rextester.com/JYF12871.  It is your code that is breaking.

Comment: I'm confused, you said it is my code that is broken, but the link you posted is back to my code. Did you mean to link to a corrected post? I also saw your comment: "And then use the simonId column appropriately." My issue is that I am not sure how to use the auto_increment to solve the problem.

Comment: Please indicate how I should use your code. I attempted to use the code in the rextexter link, but apparently did it incorrectly.  I'd like to use your solution but am completely stuck and do not know how to move forward.

Comment: @SimonRH . . . Try this link:  http://rextester.com/MYZZK17873.  Your code was at the end of the code; it wasn't properly commented out.

Comment: Now I get it! This is almost working, but if you look here http://rextester.com/WPU44316 you'll see that it always places the same value into the table. It is supposed to select the first value, then the send value if that exists.